# Reading fixed amount of bytes in C?

Tags: c

I have to write an algorithm that can read three bytes of data at a time, as such:

For example, imagine the user inputs: Uof

Uof in binary would be presented as 01010101 01101111 01100110

I need help splitting this into four equal parts of six bits each, as such:

010101 (21)

010110 (22)

111101 (61)

100110 (38)

I'm only allowed to use ints. 
I can read the first character, shift it two to the right and get the result 21 no problem.

Getting the 22 makes no sense to me. Any pointers will help, don't need the exact solution, but what's something that can get me thinking?

Comment: Step 1, use left shift to put all 24 bits into a single 32-bit `int`.  Step 2, use bitwise AND and right shift to get just the bits you want.

Comment: "Getting the 22 makes no sense to me."  That's the last two bits of the first `char` and the first four of the second.

Comment: Yeah, make sure you put all the data into a single int first. Then work on it from there.

Comment: Anybody have any tips on shifting them into one single 32 bit int?

Comment: @BenVoigt you may have missed he was asking for something to get him thinking instead of a solution. This is the right way to ask since the homework tag has been obsoleted.

Comment: @user1661781 In my answer, the third question (and the related fourth) may also help you put them all in a single int. Alternatively you can use a union (but that's not a portable way to do it).

Comment: Nevermind, I got them into one 32 bit int. Thanks everyone, should have it from here.

Comment: @AnalogFile: I did just give hints.  That's neither code nor pseudocode.  Each of those "steps" involves multiple lines of code.  Compare to Flavio's answer, which takes all the fun out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself:

- where do the 6 bits of each part come from?
- how can I move bits to a different position in a value?
- how can I combine two values so that only the interesting bits of each are taken?

To help you answer the third question you may also ask yourself:

- how can I *mask* a value so that interesting bits stay what they are and non interesting bits all become 0s (or all become 1s)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, first, we'll try to put the 3 bytes into a single integer. We'll use shift and `OR` logic. Suppose we have `a`, `b` and `c` input variables. (`Uof` would split into `a`, `b` and `c` respectively).

We first, add space for 1 more byte for the `b` variable:

```
(b << 8)
```

So `01101111` transforms to `0110111100000000`.

Now we `OR` `c` into `b`, so the zeroes are actually `c`:

```
((b << 8) | c))
```

Now, we do the same logic with `a`. We reserve more 16 bits onto the right of `a`, so we can `OR` the last expression we obtained.

```
((a << 16) | ((b << 8) | c))
```

That far, we have all the bits merged into one single 4-byte integer.

We only need to split it now, into 4 parts of 6 bit each. We'll use the *mask* logic for this.

First, when we use the "mask" logic, we have to make the mask itself. Our mask is `0x3F` (from the binary number 111111, i.e. six bits), so when we `AND` the number, with this mask, we can extract the first 6 bits on the right side:

```
r1 = (merged & 0x00003F);
```

Where `r1` stands for `result 1`.

Now, the same thing, but with the merged number 6 bits to the right, so we can take the next 6-bit number, and so on with rest:

```
r1 = ((merged >> 0)  & 0x3F);
r2 = ((merged >> 6)  & 0x3F);
r3 = ((merged >> 12) & 0x3F);
r4 = ((merged >> 18) & 0x3F);
```

So, the final code would be:

```
char /*or int*/ a, b, c;
int merged, r1, r2, r3, r4;

scanf(" %c %c %c", &a, &b, &c);

merged = ((a << 16) | ((b << 8) | c));

r1 = ((merged >> 0)  & 0x3F);
r2 = ((merged >> 6)  & 0x3F);
r3 = ((merged >> 12) & 0x3F);
r4 = ((merged >> 18) & 0x3F);

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", r1, r2, r3, r4);
```

**EDIT:** I have corrected the mask part.

Comment: What part of _don't need the exact solution, but what's something that can get me thinking?_ you did not understand?